# Why is my UIWebView appearing blank?

Tags: swift, uiwebview, xcode6, nsurl

I'm using a new view to display different web pages. I've added the UIWebView to my view and linked the delegate with the controller and the web view with an Outlet. Then I've added the following code to the controller

```
class WebPageController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = NSURL (string: "www.google.co.uk")      
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    webView.loadRequest(requestObj)
}
```

When I run the app and go to this page, the page appears blank, what have I missed?

Comment: Try to make a background color of `webView` something different than white and check if you can see it.

Comment: Also did you try `"http://www.google.co.uk/"`?

Comment: Adding http:// makes no difference and I've tried changing the colours making the background of the webView pink and the view green. When I pick the page which is white I can see the pink underneath sitting on the view which is green but my webView is just a blank white canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `http://` with your url like this.

```
let url = NSURL (string: "http://www.google.co.uk")
```

Comment: Probably "https://" would be better. Because http://www.google.co.uk redirect to it.

Comment: Using Https worked which is good but the next site which is also https still appears blank, even though I can display it on my phone in the phones browser.

Comment: @user616076 I have check it is working both with `http` & `https`, i have also try to redirect to both type page. can you show the link that you are trying.

Comment: I'm using the code above to go to this link https://www.stwater.co.uk/my-supplies/in-my-area/?tab=plumbers (preceded by https://www which this page removes) which just shows a white blank page.

Comment: It is working properly, webView load that url check this simulator image  http://i.stack.imgur.com/OxtrT.png

Comment: Thank you for trying it but I still can't get it to display either in an emulator or on my iPhone. Is there some setting I'm missing?